# SQL Query for Comparing Customer Order Amounts

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to create a query that could compare a customer's latest order purchase amount to the previous order amount of the customer's last purchase. Please see example data screenshot below:

[image: IMG1]

Ideally I'd like the query to look for these things in the results:

- Total amount from previous order before most recent order date (in this case 9/6/18 would be most recent and 2/2/17 would be the last purchase)
- Difference in amount between most recent order and last order amount ($2000-$25 = $1975)
- Create a condition in the query to look for customers whose most recent order attempt is 1000 > last purchase amount and the age of the customer's account age is > than 60 days

**Note**: These conditions for the last bullet could be modified as needed (customer's account age is > 90 days, different in order amount is $500, etc)

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: What problems do you have writing the query code?

Comment: @Mitch - it's helpful if you write a small amount of code showing the `CREATE TABLE` statement along with some sample `INSERT INTO` statements with sample data.  For example, is each order a single row?  Or might it be the sum of several rows for each order?

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service!!!  Attempt something.  If it doesn't work, post the query so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2012 onward you can use `LAG`

```
declare @amount decimal(16,2) = 1000
declare @days int = 60

select 
   *
   ,TotalWithPrevious = [Order Amount] + lag([Order Amount]) over (partition by UserID order by [Order Date] desc)
   ,DifferenceofPrevious = [Order Amount] - lag([Order Amount]) over (partition by UserID order by [Order Date] desc)
   ,CheckCondition = case 
                      when [Order Amount] - lag([Order Amount]) over (partition by UserID order by [Order Date] desc) >= @amount
                           and datediff(day,[Order Date],lag([Order Date]) over (partition by UserID order by [Order Date] desc)) >= @days 
                           then 'True' 
                           else 'False' 
                      end
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon ! is this written within a subquery?

Comment: No, it does not use a sub-query

Comment: Also @scsimon is there a way to add in the most recent order date and amount and previous order date and amount in the results as columns, thanks!

Comment: Yes, use lag as explain above.